# Check if a method does not run in Java with flag or?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, rmi

I have created a middleware/server which i'm going to use as a broker event handler when receiving data from multiply sensors in Java. Right now it receive a "new" set of data every 5 sec from the first sensor. In the mom/server, i have created a method which run every time the sensor sends a new data. I'm using RMI to get data from one to another.

I want to check if the method is not called, cant figure how to do it with flags.. have tried with a boolean called active, but it does not work very well.

When data is getting send, an example is the temperature like:

```
15, 18, 14, 19, 15, 14, 17 (one temperature every 5 sec),
```

if my sensor stops, the method which updates the data coming in will stop running, and then my while loop will just go over and over with the same data like if i stopped the sensor when 17 had just being sent:

```
15, 18, 14, 19, 15, 14, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17 (17 every round)
```

So i want to break my while loop so this does not happen :/

Any idea?

Some code:
**While loop inside mom/serv:**

```
while (true) {
        if (data == 0 && is_active == true) {

        }
        else if (data != 0 && is_active == true) {
            ar.add((byte) data);
            calculateAverage();
            System.out.println("data er: " + data);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
        else {
            break;
        }

    }
```

**The method that runs every time a new data is incoming.**

```
public void SendTemperature(byte data) throws RemoteException {
    this.data = data;       
    is_active = true;
}
```

Have an private static byte data in the top which stores the data, and that i use to calculate average and sum etc.

**UPDATE:**
I have uploaded a picture showing what i got so far.. i'm not sure if its the right way to send data in RMI to the middleware/server. Right now i have the rmi service starting at the middleware, so the sensor have to listen for active services before it can send.

All i want is to have the sensor send data to the server without the server ask for them, if u know what i mean. I have read something about RMI Callbacks, but i'm not sure what to use,

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code for reference?

Comment: This sounds like a producer/consumer scenario. Use a blocking queue: add elements with the RMI method and removes elements in your while loop.

Comment: Yeps.. its publish/subscribe

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to synchronize your code using a queue. Every time you receive some data push it to the queue. Then your handler will pick up your data and process it piece by piece. The idea is to put some functionality in the middle between your receiver and handler to synchronize those two parts.

Comment: Separate your code into three parts: the receiver that is running in a separate thread, gets some data and posts it to the queue, a synchronized queue that contain all the data needed to be processed, a handler that is running in another separate thread, reads data from the queue and handle it.

Comment: So i should make 3 classes where two of them is running its own thread?.. also when u mean Queue in java.. u mean import java.util.queue right?

Comment: A queue is an abstraction. In your case I suggest to use **java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue**. This is the first reference that I quickly found in the Internet - http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem. Hope   it will help you.

Comment: Have read it.. just a quick question.. my teacher says we need to use RMI to do this, but if i use queues, i wont have to use RMI which i have to, or have i misunderstood something? 

The producer and my sensor is like the same thing i think, right?

Comment: You can use RMI with queues. There is no problem with that. A queue is just a mechanism to synchronize your two parts.

Comment: Well , my sensor is the producer, sending data to the server.. I'm still not sure if i understand it fully, but is it right to use the queue in the server thread which handle the receiving data, and then i can take them to the other threads by this way which will handle events for example?

So is it right not to use the queue in the sensor, but only in the server program?

Comment: I don't clearly understand your statement. Please share the code you have. Then I will take a look at that.